Running a trivy scan from gradle with the bmuschko AbstractDockerRemoteApiTask
I am trying to run a trivy scan from my gradle build.
Effectively running the following command docker run aquasec/trivy image python:3.4-alpine -o mine.txt -f table
We are making use of the com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api library. According to the documentation you could extend the AbstractDockerRemoteApiTask class to run custom commands against.
I have the following in my build.gradle.kts file:
tasks.register<TrivyScanTask>("myTrivyScan") {
    filteredImageName.set("aquasec/trivy:latest")
}
    
open class TrivyScanTask : AbstractDockerRemoteApiTask {
    @Input
    val filteredImageName: Property<String> = project.objects.property(String::class)
    
    @Internal
    val imageId: Property<String> = project.objects.property(String::class)
    
    constructor() {
        onNext(Action<Image> {
            this.withGroovyBuilder {
                imageId.set(getProperty("id") as String)
            }
        })
    }
    
    override fun runRemoteCommand() {
        dockerClient...   // How can I do a custom command here
    }
    
}

This class has a dockerClient object with so many methods but nothing to execute a custom docker command against. Is there any way to achieve this using this plugin?
